# Summing array from indexes and values from other array: better way to do it in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

the goal of this question is to understand better `numpy` and its indexing capabilities by using a problem that I am constantly facing but keep writing in  a "loop" way.

Let's say I have 9 particles, and each particle has a height (in z) and a velocity (in x). I want to compute the total sum of the velocity in x as a function of z. The following code shows what I am doing:

```
import numpy as np
z = np.array([2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 4, 7]) # particle 0 on zbin 2, particle 1 on zbin 2, ...
vz = np.array([1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9]) #part1 with vx = 1.1, ...
vzmean = np.zeros_like(vz)
# can this loop be replaced by some numpy approach?
for ii in np.arange(len(z)): 
    vzmean[z[ii]] += vz[ii]
print(vzmean)
```

Output:

```
[0.  3.3 2.3 1.3 3.2 1.5 0.  1.9 0. ]
```

My question is if this loop can be replaced by a "better" numpy syntax. I have been looking at `np.unique` and its counters return but cannot get it right. As I said I want to learn if this is possible, and I am not necessarily saying that the code without loops will be better.

Of course, this is an example of a much larger problem where more memory is required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `np.bincount(z,vz)`.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. (Shall I put it as an answer?)

Comment: You can refer to the linked dup target Q&A.